# PHP replace more than two <br> to one with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
My comment has so much 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
tags
```

how to replace these br tags to one?

this one doesn't work for me 
`$text = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $text);`

Comment: The looks like a multi-line string and you are not using a multi-line modifier on your regex. That would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$text = preg_replace('~(?:<br\b[^>]*>|\R){2,}~i', "\n", $text);
```

where `\R` matches any type of newlines and `[^>]`, all characters except `>`.